# searching and replacing windows symbols in vim

Tags: regex, vim, symbols

How do I tell vim to "find" a windows symbol so I can replace it?
in particular, I am interested in replacing the plus minus sign (alt 421)

Comment: Did you try `s/<type alt-421 here>/replacement/g`?

Comment: I've not used vim for search and replace before, but it looks like it uses a pretty standard regex syntax. Have you tried `\x00B1`?

Comment: While my duplicate citation is not 1 to 1, one could follow the highest up voted answer and quickly arrive at the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`/\%u00b1`

From doc `h /\%u` : `/\%u`  match specified multibyte character (eg \%u20ac)

```
/    search
\%   extended
u    unicode
00b1 heaxadecimal code
```

Comment: Thanks! Got it working.